# How to Subscribe vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> type topic?

Tags: ros, subscribe, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello :) i wanna publish and subscribe vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> type topic, how can i do?

```
void exceptionPointsCallback(const  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr&> msg???????!!!!)

    {

        exceptions_points.clear();

        exceptions_points.swap(msg);

    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64547/how-to-subscribe-vector%3Cgeometry_msgs::posestamped%3E-type-topic?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-12-12**:
@Mohsen Hk  did you manage to make this work? Im having problem accomplishing it, and would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create  msg file "geometry_msgs_vector.msg" in "msg" directory of ur package. In msg file write

`geometry_msgs::PoseStamped [] msgs_vector`

In ur code write the subscriber like this

`void callback(const package_name::geometry_msgs_vector::ConstPtr &msg)
{`

}

To access the vector use "msg.msgs_vector"

Hope this works

PS:Dont forget to include this msg header file "package_name/geometry_msgs_vector.h" and they might be some syntactical error in the code i have mentioned but the logic is correct

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-12-12**:
@ayush_dewan i cant manage to make it work could you be more specific in how can i make this work? I really appreciate your help